Issue with Weaviate Backup Process on Azure
Description
Hello Team, I’m reaching out regarding an issue we’re experiencing with our Weaviate instance deployed on our Kubernetes development environment.
Recently, we’ve encountered difficulties with our daily database backups to Azure Blob using the Weaviate backup API. Our backup script is failing consistently due to a previous failure of the Weaviate backup instance.
Specifically, we’re receiving the following error message: “Cannot create new backup. Backup ‘gaibot-weaviate-backup_20240417000000’ is not yet released. This means its contents have not yet been fully copied to its destination. Please try again later.”
Unfortunately, we’re unsure about how to proceed to release the old backup and resume our development activities.
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue.
Server Setup Information
Weaviate Server Version:
Deployment Method: Kubernetes
Number of Running Nodes: One node
Weaviate Version: 1.19.1
enter image description here
I have try to run backup instance multiple times still not able to resolved

Duda from Weaviate here.
1.19.1 is an "old" version and a lot have changed since this release.
https://forum.weaviate.io/t/issue-with-weaviate-backup-process-on-azure/2094, some users were able to release the backup process by restarting the server.
Have you tried this?
Thanks!
